# jQuery Validation isn't returning span

Tags: jquery, validation

So I'm creating a register page for my website and the validation isn't throwing back any of the 'Missing data' spans, I have been following a tutorial but somehow mine isn't working. My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme3.css">
<title>Register</title>
<style>
.error{
    color: red;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
        <div id="container">
            <h1>Registration Form</h1>
            <div id="regForm"
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
                    <div><label for="fname">First Name</label><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"></div>
                    <div><label for="lname">Last Name</label><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"></div>
                    <div><label for="username">Username</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username"></div>
                    <div><label for="password">Password</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password"></div>
                    <div><label for="email">Email Address</label><input type="email" name="email" id="email"></div>
                    <div><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#submit').click(function(){
            $('error').remove();
            var fname = $('#fname').val();
            var lname = $('#lname').val();
            var username = $('#username').val();
            var password = $('#password').val();  
            var email = $('#email').val();
            var emailReg = /^([\w=\.]+@([\w=]+\.)+[\w=](2,4})?$/;
            var errors = false;

            if(fname=="") {
                errors = true;
                $('label[for=fname]').after('<span class="error">Missing data</span>');
            }
            if(lname=="") {
                errors = true;
                $('label[for=lname]').after('<span class="error">Missing data</span>');
            }
            if(username=="") {
                errors = true;
                $('label[for=username]').after('<span class="error">Missing data</span>');
            }
            if(password=="") {
                errors = true;
                $('label[for=password]').after('<span class="error">Missing data</span>');
            }
            else if(password==username){
                errors = true;
                $('label[for=password]').after('<span class="error">password and username match, try again</span>');
            }
            if(email=="") {
                errors = true;
                $('label[for=email]').after('<span class="error">Missing data</span>');
            }else if(!emailReg.test(email)){
                errors = true;
                $('label[for=email]').after('<span class="error">Email is not valid</span>');
            }
            if(errors==false){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your code. There is not much we can do to help you without it.

Comment: I have, it's hyperlinked to 'my code'

Comment: Missed that. Sorry. The hyperlink isn't showing on my phone for some reason.

Comment: That's fine, got any idea of what's wrong? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes around your Regex on line 41. Try this:

```
var emailReg = '/^([\w=\.]+@([\w=]+\.)+[\w=](2,4})?$/';
```

The span is showing up after the label, which is where you told it to. If you want it to show up after the input field, use this. Change the name for each field:

```
 $("#fname").after('<span class="error"> Missing Data</span>');
```

Comment: The span is showing up after the label, which is where you told it to. If you want it to show up after the input field, use this. Change the name for each field:
$("#fname").after('<span class="error"> Missing Data</span>');

Answer (score 0):

Let me start with a quick fix: I believe you meant to select DOM elements with the *class* error:

```
$('.error').remove();
```

Here are two major considerations:

Firstly, make sure you are binding the click event when you are certain that the submit DOM element has been loaded. You might want to wrap your Javascript in $(document).ready() callback. Even though your Javascript is explicitly written after the html, it is still good practice to use the .ready() function to be absolutely sure that the DOM elements have loaded.

Secondly, make sure to stop the form submission. Currently, the client will click submit and be taken to a different page before they can see the Javascript in action. We need to use Javascript to first validate the data, and then decide if we want to proceed with the form submission. We can use preventDefault() and stopPropagation() to stop the form submission if we detect empty input.

```
// wait for document to be ready and then attach behavior to events
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    // since document has loaded, we know that the #submit element is on the page
    $('#submit').click(function(e) {
        // remove all previous .error messages
        $('.error').remove();
        var fname = $('#fname').val();
        var lname = $('#lname').val();
        if (fname == '') {
            $('label[for=fname]').after('<span class="error"> Missing data</span>');
            // the user gave us invalid input so invoke these functions on the event to
            // prevent the form from submitting
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
        if (lname == '') {
            $('label[for=lname]').after('<span class="error"> Missing data</span>');
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the JSFiddle that is working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/NALG4/1/

Hope this helps!